# Print value one by one from controller in asp.net MVC, when controller is called from ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a **AJAX** call for controller as below,

```
function print(response, endpoint) {
        $(".tt").append("<tr><td>" + JSON.stringify(response[0], null) + "</td><td>" + JSON.stringify(response[1], null) + "</td><td>" + JSON.stringify(response[2], null) + "</td><td>" + JSON.stringify(response[3], null) + "</td><td>" + JSON.stringify(endpoint, null) + "</td></tr>");
    } 

   $(".submit").click(function () {
            var env = $("#env").find(":selected").text();
            var region = $("#region").find(":selected").text();
            var country = $("#country").find(":selected").text()
            var folderPath = $.trim($('#folderPath').val());



                var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                    contentType: "application/json ;charset=utf-8",
                    type: "GET",
                    async: false,
                    url: "/Home/GetmyModel" + "?selcetion=" + env + "&region=" + region + "&country=" + country + "&folderpath=" + folderPath,
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response != null) {
                            //print(response, endpoints[i]);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (exception) {
                    },
                    complete: function (data) {
                    }
                });
```

My controller goes like this

```
public void GetmyModel(string selcetion, string region, string country, string folderpath)
        {

foreach (var item in System.IO.File.ReadLines(folderpath))
            {
//do some work with return value as list<string>
//show list<string> in table in view using either print method of JS or by another way 
}

}
```

Everything works fine if i send complete response back by making return type as `JsonResult`. However i am not understanding how can i print each item.

Comment: What output you expect?

Comment: i want to write output of type string in table,as in Print javascript function

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. You method should return a collection (as  `JsonResult`, and then you loop through each item in the collection (using `$.each()` or a `for` loop) to generate the elements

Comment: After performing some work with item, the result of which i want to show on UI

Comment: Does the code in your controller method generate a `List<string>`, and do you want to generate a `<table>` with each item in the collection output to a table cell?

Comment: basically i don't want to wait for complete response to come. I want to show the result as soon the //do work is done for one item is done

Comment: That is not possible unless you make separate ajax calls for each line in your file (and you would need to pass a value indicating the index of the line)